# change background color of strip table using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

My problem is simple.

This is my HTML

```
<table id="SubTransTable" class="table table-info table-striped mb30">
```

jQuery

```
 $('#SubTransTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
            var tr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
            if (tr.classList.contains('selected')) {
                tr.classList.remove('selected');
                // SelectedIDs.pop($(this).data().id);
                var id = SubTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data().id;

            }
            else {
                //Remove For Multi Select
                SubTable.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');

                tr.classList.add('selected');

                var id = SubTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data().id;
            }
        });
```

This is the result.

[image]

The result that the `tr` has the `selected` class but it is overridded with the bootstrap class.
If I remove the  `table-striped` class from the table it works correct.

Now the question is clear how to keep the strip class and do the select event without being overrided.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.selected{
  background-color: #71d1eb !important;
}
```

Try to add `!important`